# Difficulty with Phonegap/Genymotion

Tags: android, css, cordova

I am following a tutorial to build an exercise tracker app This one: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-exercise-tracking-app-geolocation-tracking--mobile-11070

I have installed phonegap/cordova properly I believe, and I´m using the genymotion android emulator as I find it to be faster.

I believe that I have followed the steps in the tutorial properly, but it won´t display the page right. Seems that there is some problems with the css-formatting. First of all, everything looks chaotic, like if something has crashed. Then I change the emulator to "flip" the phone and back again, and it looks normal. However no style formatting. Any ideas?

Here is a photo of how it looks in my folder which i run it from, and how it looks in the emulator.

I am sick of all the installments necessary and finally hoped that I got it to work haha. Hope that its not much more to be done. Not sure if it is relevant, but i use a mac and edit my code in sublime text2.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a problem linking the script. I got the same problem as you and I fixed it by replacing them.

The code was like this:

```
-script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"
```

and then I realized that the entire path wasn't there so I change it to:

```
-script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/cordova/cordova-1.7.0.js"
```

and it work perfectly.